# Force display of ticks on xAxes using chartkick gem and chart.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, visualization, chartkick

I'm using Chartkick and Chart.js to visualize a data set of two lines, however, only the first tick on the x-axis displays

I've tried passing options to the dataset as per the chart.js docs, indicating that I would not like the ticks to auto skip.

```
<%= line_chart [
      { name: "Successes", data: @successful_requests },
      { name: "Errors", data: @error_requests }
    ],
    dataset:{
      scaleShowValues: true,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    legend: "bottom",
    messages: { empty: "Awaiting your first request!" }  
%>
```

I expect the chart to show a dataset an x-axis that is labeled at all points on the x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

[autoSkip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration)

> If true, automatically calculates how many labels can be shown and hides labels accordingly.

[maxTicksLimit](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html)

> Maximum number of ticks and gridlines to show.

The `autoSkip` option controls whether some of the *labels* on the axes ticks are automatically skipped when the label texts would otherwise overlap. To control the number of *ticks* being displayed, what you're looking for is `maxTicksLimit` and related options. For your use case, you should probably set `maxTicksLimit` depending on the size of your data sets.

Also, these options can't be set on the `datasets` directly. Instead, you need to pass them through Chartkick to Chart.js by using the `library` option. So, something like this should achieve what you're trying to do:

```rb
<%= line_chart [
      { name: "Successes", data: @successful_requests },
      { name: "Errors", data: @error_requests }
    ],
    library: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: @successful_requests.size
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    legend: "bottom",
    messages: { empty: "Awaiting your first request!" }  
%>
```

Note that I'm assuming both your data sets are always of the same length.