# Setting ticks of Chart.js in html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I'm using chartkick with chart.js in Ruby on Rails. I saw the documentation and some issues, but I can't find anything to solve my problem.

I'm setting my chart in html.erb file, like this:

```
<%=
    line_chart $hash_chart,
        options: {
            max: $value.max+5,
            min: $value.min-5,
            allowDecimals: false,
            colors: color_line,
            xtitle: "Title of x axis",
            ytitle: "Title of y axis",
            discrete: true,
            points: false,
            width: "500px",
            height: "500px",
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    distribution: 'linear'
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    distribution: 'linear',
                    type: 'category', (part of a configuration attempt)
                    categories: $time, (part of a configuration attempt)
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
%>
```

The settings until height param works, but scales settings doesn't. The answer of this issue is exactly what I make (according documentation of Chart.js), but didn't work: [Force display of ticks on xAxes using chartkick gem and chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719975/force-display-of-ticks-on-xaxes-using-chartkick-gem-and-chart-js). I tried to put this setting inside library brace too.

Basically, I want to set the ticks in x Axis and show just some labels of my array of datas. Is it possible to format this (using this type of file)?

Comment: Should the values for height and width be quoted as strings?

Comment: Yes, I wrote wrong, sorry. They need to be string. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong old v2 syntax of chart.js, the scales in v3 for example have to be configured like this

```js
scales: {
  x:{
    ticks: {}
  },
  y: {
  // Y config
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Since you are on V2 your syntax of declaring axis is correct, make sure you dont run the latest version of chartKick since it uses v3.

`distribution` does not do anything unless your scale type is `time`. The `stepSize` only works for linear and time scales so you will need to change `type: 'category'` to `type: 'linear'` or if you are using time data to `type: 'time'` if you are using time data the stepsize has to be configured in the `time` sub part so you will need to change `ticks` to `time`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm actually using version 2.6 of Chart.js (due to a compatibility issue with another library), but I tried to do that too. I can't get stepSize to work.

Comment: Updated answer for you

Comment: After some tries, I found one of the errors. I forgot to import a file to chart.js. Also, the options brace didn't work, so I removed and I did all the things you said, was very helpfull. Thanks.